# How to remove an nested array element from Array

Tags: mongodb

I want to remove an nested array element if its **first value** is 0 from array.
The data is shown below.

```
[
  {
    "data": [[0,1],[2,3],[0,3],[4,5]]
  }
]
```

[test case](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yEl9AErapCd)

And here is my solution, which doesn't work.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "data": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "0": 0
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Mongo version 4.2+ you can use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) like so:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "datum",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$datum",
                  0
                ]
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LJH7TQ2pQ_H)